# Access DataItem object on RepeaterItemCommand

Tags: c#, asp.net

how I can to access my Repeater DataItem when a fire button command?
I can see that DataItem return null.

There is some possibility?

Comment: Repeater data items are not retained on a postback.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/3890934/330180

Comment: I have to pass the parameter in CommandArgument only?

Answer (score 1):

set the id of the object in the CommandArgument of the button. then in the button command event you can access the id from e.CommandArgument. you can then query the domain/db for the data.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure it's not a header row, where you see that `DataItem` is `null`.

You can do it by encapsulating your code with `if` statement simply checking if `DataItem` is not `null` or if it's of a specified type you use to assign data to that `Repeater`.

Alternatively you can check [ListItemType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemtype.aspx) of an item as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound.aspx or here: [ASP.Net repeater item.DataItem is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649192/asp-net-repeater-item-dataitem-is-null).

You should then be able to access data associated with each of the items in [ItemDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound.aspx) event by accessing `e.Item.DataItem` object.

If you want to access data assigned to the repeater from another event invoked from control bound (i.e. button click like you mentioned) you can use `CommandArgument` and assign appropriate value to it for each of the items and handle `ButtonCommand`.